Access structure property from editor react component in ketcher react
I am building a web application in react with a molecular structure editor.
Using the example from ketcher-standalone, I got this editor working:
import {useState} from "react"
import {StandaloneStructServiceProvider} from "ketcher-standalone"
import {Editor} from "ketcher-react"
import "ketcher-react/dist/index.css"

const structServiceProvider = new StandaloneStructServiceProvider()

const KetcherEditor = () => {

    // this is what i would like to use
    const [structure, setStructure] = useState('')
    
    return(
        <Editor
            staticResourcesUrl=""
            structServiceProvider={structServiceProvider}
            errorHandler={message => console.error(message)}
        />
    )
}

export default KetcherEditor

However, I would like to access the structure drawn in the editor to process and store it. For that, I want to use the useState hook. I have not found any documentation on how to pass the state setter to the editor component.
How can I access the structure property?

Sometimes components allow to pass a ref to a component and it set the ref as the component's api using useImperativeHandle. I'm not familiar with ketcher-react but maybe they do that too

You may find some usage here https://github.com/epam/ketcher/tree/master/example.
And ketcher have an init method https://github.com/epam/ketcher/blob/7343fddd2c979c31fefdcba21e5df0687167a842/example/src/App.tsx#L99. You can call setStructure(ketcher) after window.ketcher = ketcher.
P.S. window.ketcher is required, otherwise paste(ctrl + v) will raise a error.
